# URL rewriting using .htaccess, query string as file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

If my URL is http://www.xyz.com/index.php?view=abc 
then it should open 
http://www.xyz.com/abc.php

What should I write in .htaccess??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which do you want your end users to type into their browsers? `index.php?view=abc` (which is unusual from normal rewriting), or `abc.php`?  The way you asked doesn't make it clear which your users will see.

Comment: actually I want if user will open index.php?view=abc then abc.php will be execute. and if user enters directly abc.php then he/she can not open that page. User must need to access it via index.php?view=abc.

Answer (score 2):

> If my URL is http://www.xyz.com/index.php?view=abc then it should open http://www.xyz.com/abc.php

You don't need .htaccess for that, simply put in index.php

```
$view = $_GET['view'];
if (strpos($view, '/') === false && $view != "index" && file_exists("$view.php"))
  require "$view.php";
```

Be sure not to have any other vulnerable php files in your root directory (but I'd recommend using other/better techniques to check the user input from the url).

---

If you wanted to have the rewriting *the other way round*, your `.htaccess` could look similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+).php$  /index.php?view=$1  [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Czechnology.
It works.
but what if I need reverse case. if some one types URL like,
www.xyz.com/login.php then it should be redirect to,
www.xyz.com/index.php?view=login

Comment: @user985361, isn't that exactly what's in the second part of my answer?